# Azure ClaimsIdentity when Switching to Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I recently switched my ASP.NET app to ASP.NET Identity away from Azure's Active Directory configuration. I had no problems when testing this locally, but when I publish to Azure I get the following error:

> A claim of type
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier'
>   or
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider'
>   was not present on the provided ClaimsIdentity. To enable anti-forgery
>   token support with claims-based authentication, please verify that the
>   configured claims provider is providing both of these claims on the
>   ClaimsIdentity instances it generates. If the configured claims
>   provider instead uses a different claim type as a unique identifier,
>   it can be configured by setting the static property
>   AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier.

Is there something I should have changed on my Azure side as far as configuration? Or is there something else I need in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you’re not using ACS as your STS then the above error pretty much tells you what’s needed to solve the problem.

You need to tell MVC which claim you want to use to uniquely identify the user. You do this by setting the AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier property (typically in App_Start in global.asax). For example (assuming you want to use nameidentifier as the unique claim):

AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
}
```

Comment: This is what did it for me. Thanks!